# Seeking land use map in London and UK?

Tags: data, united-kingdom, land-use

I am looking for the land use data of London in vector format, preferably in polygons. I am interested in whether a building / an area is residential, office or retail use, like this one (https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-spatial-distribution-of-three-key-land-use-categories-in-Inner-London_fig5_301482105).

But I tried to download several datasets including Strategi® which includes developed land use areas. But unfortunately, no land use attributes are available in the shapefile. I could only find the data from UMMAP product from Verisk: http://www.geoinformationgroup.co.uk/ukmap But the data is not an open data.

Where can I find the open free land use map for London and the UK?

Comment: Open data availability questions should be asked at the respective [Open Data SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/), but is this what you were looking for: https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset?q=land%20use ? I found this, simply by searching for "city of london open data". And to help you even further, the feature classes for London can be found [here](https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/london-area-classification). You will have to join the data with the feature class yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I asked the question here because I found a similar question earlier but the solution cannot help me much. And I knew the dataset you just mentioned. But unfortunately, it is the dataset the statistics by ward. I am interested in a finer scale data i.e. the land uses of each building or each smaller area.

Comment: In that case, after some rigorous searching, have a look [here](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/hm-land-registry-data/public-data) and specifically [here](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/hm-land-registry-commercial-and-corporate-ownership-data).

Answer (score -1):

Digimap is not particulary "open" but you can access it if you are associated with an institution that has a partnership with them, so you should give it a try.

https://digimap.edina.ac.uk

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I inquired Digimap before. They don't have the land use dataset either. They suggest me UMMAP product from Verisk as well, which is not open.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look in:

https://maps.london.gov.uk/gla/rest/services/IMA/IMA_context_information_landuse/MapServer

Connect as a server connection from your GIS client, folder IMA, map IMA_contect_information_landuse, dataset land_use

This is the best I have found for London so far.

Comment: Theo, thank you very much. That's really helpful. Do you know if it is possible for me to retrieve the data in different layers? Because I am interested in the residential layer which should have the value of 11. But I cannot see the properties table of the dataset in QGIS.